# Quel est le rapport entre bateleur et magicien ?

Tags: définition

En jouant a Persona 5, j'ai vu que la carte de tarot "The magician" (Le magicien) est traduite par "le Bateleur" sur la carte.

[image]

Mais je me suis demandé... y a-t-il un rapport entre un magicien et un bateleur (la recherche que je fais me donne juste que c'est un type d'oiseau)

Connaissant le tarot, ça pourrait être du vieux français mais je vois difficilement le rapport.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selon [le dictionnaire de l'Académie française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9B0607), un bateleur est (l'emphase est mienne) :

> ***Vieilli.*** Forain qui, sur les places publiques et les marchés, fait des tours d’acrobatie ou d’**escamotage**, joue des scènes bouffonnes, etc. *S’amuser aux pitreries d’un bateleur. Une troupe de bateleurs à l’entrée d’un cirque.*

De nos jours, on parlerait plutôt de prestidigitateur.

Comment: En gros on parle d'un magicien de rue, qui fait des tours de passe passe ou des trucs de cartes, et non pas un magicien fantastique, genre Gandalf (ce que javais en tête).

Comment: Oui, c'est exactement ça.

Answer (score 4):

- le bateleur = tarot de Marseille
- le magicien = tarot Rider-Wait-Smith

Historiquement le tarot de Marseille est plus ancien et Wait s'est servi des bases du tarot de Marseille pour créer le sien beaucoup plus ésotérique.

C'est (presque) la même carte au niveau symbolisme mais la première est française, l'autre anglaise.